# Word for a person that never looks back (to the past)

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe someone that never looks to the past. Someone that never considers whether the choices they made were the right ones, someone that cares only about what is currently happening and about what will.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend a negative valence, such a person could also be called *unreflective*,  *incurious*, or *lacking self-awareness*. Failing to learn from the past is *ignorance*.

Answer (score 0):

Such a person could be called ***forward-looking***:

> planning for or anticipating possible future events, conditions, etc.; progressive. ([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/forward-looking))

or

> planning for and thinking about the future in a positive way, especially by being willing to use modern methods or ideas ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/forward-looking))